# ¿Cómo citar DRAE en línea en un artículo técnico -- "(2017)"?

Tags: dle, escritura, citas

How should I cite DRAE in a scholarly article?  I think it's:

> Real Academia Española (201x)

But I'm not sure what year to put in parentheses.

Comment: Esta nota te puede servir: https://blognisaba.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/apa-cmo-citar-el-diccionario-de-la-real-academia-en-lnea/ . La 23.ª edición es del 2014.

Comment: In fact you should say something like _Real Academia Española (201x). Diccionario... (23.ª ed.)_

Comment: También es útil ver la plantilla que usan en Wikipedia para esto: [Cita DRAE](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantilla:Cita_DRAE). Sale de la forma _Real Academia Española (2014). «a chorros: copiosamente, con rapidez.». Diccionario de la lengua española (23.ª edición). Madrid: Espasa._.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En el DLE existe la sección [Modo de cita](https://dle.rae.es/contenido/cita) que da indicaciones precisas:

> REAL ACADEMIA ESPAÑOLA: Diccionario de la lengua española, 23.ª ed., [versión 23.3 en línea]. `<https://dle.rae.es>` [Fecha de la consulta].

---

Para una visión más general, cabe destacar que en la web de la Real Academia Española, sección [Preguntas frecuentes](http://www.rae.es/consultas-linguisticas/preguntas-frecuentes), hay un imagen-enlace con el título "Citas y reproducciones". Nos lleva a la web https://www.conlicencia.com/rae, donde no dan explicaciones sobre el estilo a usar.

angus [mencionó](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20100/c%C3%B3mo-citar-drae-en-l%C3%ADnea-en-un-art%C3%ADculo-t%C3%A9cnico-2017#comment30382_20100) en los comentarios la entrada de blog [APA: cómo citar el diccionario de la Real Academia en línea](https://blognisaba.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/apa-cmo-citar-el-diccionario-de-la-real-academia-en-lnea/). Navegando en ella, nos encontramos con una detallada explicación sobre la metodología de la American Psychological Association (APA), que parece ser la más extendida:

> **¿Cómo se cita el DRAE en APA?**
>
> No podemos pasar a hacer el modelo del DRAE sin ver el ejemplo que aporta el mismo manual del APA en donde se emplea precisamente esta obra en el ejemplo 28, una obra en lengua distinta del inglés cuyo título ha sido traducido. Lo reproduzco tal cual, solo por fidelidad a la fuente:
>
> > Real Academia Española. (2001). Diccionario de la lengua española [Dictionary of the Spanish Language] (22nd ed.). Madrid, Spain: Author.
>
> Desde luego, si traducimos esto al español y le aplicamos nuestras propias reglas ortográficas, tendríamos esto:
>
> > Real Academia Española. (2001). Diccionario de la lengua española (22.a ed.). Madrid, España: Autor.

Luego sigue con la parte que responde explícitamente a tu pregunta:

> **¿Cómo se cita el DRAE en línea?**
>
> Una vez vistos los modelos de APA, la respuesta es en realidad muy sencilla. La referencia bibliográfica del diccionario en línea de la RAE se vería así:
>
> > Real Academia Española. (2001). Diccionario de la lengua española (22.a ed.). Consultado en http://www.rae.es/rae.html
>
> Y una entrada del mismo diccionario, se vería así:
>
> > Real Academia Española. (2001). Disquisición. En Diccionario de la lengua española (22.a ed.). Recuperado de http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=disquisici%F3n

¿Qué edición y año es el actual? En su página [Diccionario de la lengua española](http://www.rae.es/obras-academicas/diccionarios/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola), la RAE enlaza un [pdf](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Ediciones_DRAE_17-10-2014.pdf) con la lista de todas las ediciones y su año de publicación. Allí vemos que la edición más actual (a marzo de 2017) es la 23.ª, que fue editada en 2014. Por tanto, diríamos:

> Real Academia Española. (2014). Diccionario de la lengua española (23.ª ed.). Consultado en http://www.rae.es/rae.html

---

Encontré por cierto una web que genera la citaciones automáticamente: http://www.cva.itesm.mx/biblioteca/pagina_con_formato_version_oct/apa.htm

Answer (score 1):

Dado lo cambiante de la información online, hay que añadir la fecha en que fue consultado el diccionario.

Por ejemplo, en la página correspondiente del CORDE [citar](http://corpus.rae.es/citar.htm) se indica (negrita mía]:

> REAL ACADEMIA ESPAÑOLA: Banco de datos (CORDE) [en línea]. Corpus diacrónico del español. http://www.rae.es **[Fecha de la consulta]**
>
> REAL ACADEMIA ESPAÑOLA: Banco de datos (CREA) [en línea]. Corpus de referencia del español actual. http://www.rae.es **[Fecha de la consulta]**

Y más concretamente para el DLE [citar](https://dle.rae.es/contenido/cita):

> REAL ACADEMIA ESPAÑOLA: Diccionario de la lengua española, 23.ª ed., [versión 23.3 en línea]. https://dle.rae.es **[Fecha de la consulta]**.

Answer (score 0):

No me convence las explicaciones dadas por una razón, poner las fechas entre paréntesis es propio del sistema anglosajón como lo señala el APA. Hoy en día las explicaciones de la REA dejan mucho que desear y no diría que son fiables, toda vez que cambian de opinión cada 3 días, lo más correcto siguiendo los lineamientos de las reglas de la lengua española sería:

> Real Academia Española. Diccionario de la Lengua Española, 22a edición, 2001.

Es necesario señalar el autor, obra y datos, fecha y lugar.

Comment: en cualquier caso, _22a_ debería ser _22.ª_.

Comment: Lugar has olvidado